# Laravel get all parents of category

Tags: php, laravel

I have categories and subcategories in laravel

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

And I can add a new category which belongs to an already created category. Something like "Test -> subcategory of test" and then let's say I will create "sub-subcategory of test" which belongs to subcategory of test which will look like this: "Test -> subcategory of test -> sub-subcategory of test"
And in the view I want to print the parents of the category if it has any.
I do it like this:

```
@if($category->parent)
   <td>{{ $category->parent->name }} <strong>-></strong> {{ $category->name }}</td>
@else
   <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>    
@endif
```

But this only shows one parent category ("subcategory of test -> sub-subcategori of test"). I want to show all the parents which will look like this: "Test->subcategory of test -> sub-subcategory of test"
How can I do that?

Comment: For something like this I would suggest looking at Nested sets. You might find this package useful: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could define a model accessor on `Cateory` model that retrieves all parents and puts them into a collection. So in your `Category` model add the following method:

```
public function getParentsAttribute()
{
    $parents = collect([]);

    $parent = $this->parent;

    while(!is_null($parent)) {
        $parents->push($parent);
        $parent = $parent->parent;
    }

    return $parents;
}
```

then in your blade template you can fetch all the parents of a category

```
@if(count($category->parents))
    <td>{{ $category->parents->implode('-') }} <strong>-></strong> {{ $category->name }}</td>
@else
    <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
@endif
```

I see no other solution different from recursively retrieving all the parents and the package suggested by @Ross Wilson in the comments. Take into account that the number of queries will be equal to the number of the parent categories.

Another thing that you could do is setting the parent tree into the DB in the `categories` table, to save a lot of queries. Add in your `categories` table a string field like `parents_tree` and at save/update time set this value with the parent names already concatenated. This is a little dirty because if one of the parents change its name you have to update all the children accordingly. Is up to you to which trade-off you want to succumb.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it but in the view it throws error "Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation" any idea why is that?

Comment: Are you trying to do `$category->parents()` with the `()` brackets?

Comment: I was trying without the brackets
now I added them and it works fine thanks!

Comment: Oh i see, you've not defined the method as a model accessor but as a plain model method. That's also fine. Glad it helped

Answer (score 5):

you can append the parent variable:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $appends = [
        'parent'
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

It's the shortest solution, but this is not the best way, since then every time a parent object is loaded. Better do this:

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function getParentsNames() {
    if($this->parent) {
        return $this->parent->getParentsNames(). " > " . $this->name;
    } else {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

In your blade you call: `{{ $category->getParentsNames() }}`

Comment: By using this .. i have in my selecbox options
Electronics
Buldings
Electronics > Laptop
Cars
Electronics > Computer

so it's not best for sorting! you get that?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but here is the correct answer for anybody in the future.  This will get you unlimited categories

In Category Model

```
    public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function getParentsNames() {

    $parents = collect([]);

    if($this->parent) { 
        $parent = $this->parent;
        while(!is_null($parent)) {
            $parents->push($parent);
            $parent = $parent->parent;
        }
        return $parents;
    } else {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

In Blade  (I am sure you can do this on the model level also but here is my fast way of doing it)

```
 @if ($category->getParentsNames() !== $category->name)
                                @foreach ($category->getParentsNames()->reverse() as $item)
                                    @if ($item->parent_id == 0)
                                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/{{ $item->slug }}">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
                                             @else
                                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="../{{ $item->slug }}">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach  
                            @endif
```

Result Home / Living Room / Sofa / Couch

Answer (score 1):

So far, the best solution I have found is to use a **Nested set model**.
Detailed explanation / implementation are quit long and there's already plenty of subject about that. So I will shorten the subject.

The idea is to group categories with values that are between parent values and so on.
Ex:

```
Clothes : 1-10
    - T-shirts: 2-3
    - Pants: 4-9
        - Shorts 5-6
        - Joggers 7-8
```

Using theses values, it becomes very easy to query all the ascendants or descendants categories using only one query as they are always contained between two values.

One major drawback is; when categories changes (created / deleted / moved), it requires to re-evaluate and update the nodes.

---

Here's (IMO) the best explanation I have found: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

I have also found this library that seems to works quit nicely https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 0):

Mine only note to get to the main category, maybe it will be useful to someone.

```
 static function  getDepth($parent_id) {

       $categories= Categories::find($parent_id);

       if ($categories) {
           if ($categories->parent_id == 0) {
               return $categories->category_name;
           } else {
               return self::getDepth($categories->parent_id);
           }
       }

    }
```

blade.php

```
   <td>{{ \App\Models\Admin\Category::getDepth($category->parent_id)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

// Category Model:

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, parent_id')->with('subCategories');
}

public function parentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

// Controller:

```
public function getAllCategoryWithChild(Request $request) {
    $categories = Category::with(['subCategories','parentCategory.subCategories']);
    $categories->whereDoesntHave('parentCategory');
    $categories = $categories->paginate($request->get('per_page', 10));
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories)
}
```