# Get all parents of child category

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to get all of its main categories if the product category is a subcategory.

I read this article:[Laravel get all parents of category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997680/laravel-get-all-parents-of-category) .but I could not adapt my own project

I have one category table in DB. - category
And if category is the main category his main_id = 0 but if it subcategory main_id is parent id.
İ need to get categories like that sub->parent->parent....Parent
How can i do this? Thanks

My Category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
protected $table = 'category';
protected $fillable = ['category_name', 'slug', 'main_id'];


public function index() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory');
}
public function productt(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SubCategory','category_sub');
}
public static function getCategory($parent = 0, $string = '-1'){
    $categories = Category::where('main_id', '=', $parent)->get();

    $string = $string+1;
    foreach($categories as $category){
        echo "<option value='$category->id'>".str_repeat('-', 
  $string).$category->category_name."</option>";
        Category::getCategory($category->id, $string);
    }

 }
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'main_id');
}

public function children()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'main_id');
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get the parents like this:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$collection = collect();
do {
    $collection->push($category->parent);
    $category = $category->parent;
} while($category->parent()->exists())
```

Keep in mind that this method ends up with the `$category` variable as the highest
parent in the chain.